# Split text based on dot in R

Tags: regex, r, strsplit

I have:

```
"word1.word2"
```

and I want:

```
"word1" "word2"
```

I know I have to use `strsplit` with perl=TRUE, but I can't find the regular expression for a period (to feed to the split argument).

Comment: Do you really need a regex for this?

Comment: `strsplit(str1, '[.]')[[1]]` should do it or use `\\.`

Answer (score 19):

There are several ways to do this, both with base R and with the common string processing packages (like "stringr" and "stringi").

Here are a few in base R:

```
str1 <- "word1.word2"

strsplit(str1, ".", fixed = TRUE)  ## Add fixed = TRUE
strsplit(str1, "[.]")              ## Make use of character classes
strsplit(str1, "\\.")              ## Escape special characters
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
library(stringr)
a <- "word1.word2"
str_split(a, "\\.")
```